# Probability of getting 20 in two rolls of a fair pair of 6 sided dice?

Tags: probability

This is an elementary probability question. But I'm a bit stuck. A pair of 6-sided (fair) dice is rolled twice. What is the probability of getting a total of 20 ?

My soln:
P(20) = P(12 & 8) + P(11 & 9) + P(10 & 10) + P(10 & 10) + P(9 & 11) + P(8 & 12)

Should P(10 & 10) be included twice or just once and why ?

Comment: Just once.  Think of it this way:  suppose one die is blue and the other red.  Then the event $(12,\;8)$, say, can occur in two ways (Blue $12$ Red $8$ or Blue $8$ Red $12$).  But $(10,10)$ can only occur one way.

Comment: @lulu I agree that it's just once, but using one blue and one red die like that is likely confusing, since the setup is "throw one pair of dice, then throw the same pair once again". I assume the OP split the results up by "sum of pips on first throw" and "sum of pips on second throw", but you've gone orthogonal to that and said "sum of the blue pips on the two throws" vs. "sum of red pips on the two throws".

Comment: Intuitively you are correct. But here we are counting the total of four dice. Isn't the probability of getting 10&10 twice of that say 12&8 ?

Comment: @thethakuri  I was (incorrectly) reading the problem as if it referred to the rolling of a pair of ten sided dice, but it doesn't matter.  Instead of Blue and Red, think of First and Second.  The only way to get $(10,\;10)$ is for BOTH First and Second to yield $10$.  You can get $(12,\;8)$ in two ways:  First yields $12$ Second $8$ or First yields $8$ and Second $12$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's often good to think about simpler problems where it's easier to check the answer. If you throw two coins, what's the probability that the number of heads is $2$? Should you count $1\,\&\,1$ once or twice?

Alternatively, consider the sum $p_2+p_3+\cdots+p_{11}+p_{12}=1$ and its square that represents the possible results of your experiment:

$$(p_2+p_3+\cdots+p_{11}+p_{12})(p_2+p_3+\cdots+p_{11}+p_{12})=1\;.$$

How often does the term $p_{10}p_{10}$ occur in its expansion?

Comment: Thanks. Your analogy with the sum & square makes sense.